# sqlite how to cache a table optimally?

Tags: database, sqlite, caching, database-design

Say I have a table in my sqlite database file, named `luluTable`. Also I have two separate processes `source_process` and `sink_process` that have open connections into that database.

**the problem:**

`source_process` edits a row of `luluTable` and then indicates it to `sink_process` through `ipc`. Then `sink_process` gets the `ipc` message, then reads the modified row in `luluTable` (with the help of `ipc` contents) and then validates the modified row. If the modified row is valid, `sink_process` send and `ACK` to `source_process`, otherwise it sends a `NACK` via `ipc`.

If `source_process` gets a `NACK`, how can it change back the modified row of `luluTable` into its initial values?!

**my very first solution:**

use two tables instead of one: `luluTable` and `luluTableCache`. `luluTableCache` is the modified version of `luluTable`. `source_process` at first changes just `luluTableCache`. Then `sink_process` just reads `luluTableCache` and starts it verification procedure. If `source_process` gets an `ACK`, then *commits* `luluTableCache` into `luluTable`; otherwise it deletes `luluTableCache` and releases `luluTable` untouched.

**my question:**

Is there any more-optimum solution than mine??!! My solution doubles the size of my database and also CPU performances, because it needs to read/write on two tables instead of one. Are there any APIs in `sqlite3` for your suggested operations?!

Comment: Are you using a programming language such as Java or C# with your SQLite database?

Comment: I am using `C` version of sqlite3 APIs; but what's the difference?

Comment: Well many languages have ORM technologies which also can serve as a cache between the caller and the database.  That is, depending on how you plan on using your database, caching would already be taken care of.

Comment: that's not my case; assume I'm using `sqlite` in an embedded environment with pure `C`

Comment: Send the new data to the verifying process and only actually store it in the DB if it's approved?

Comment: @Shawn and what if there is a lot of tables which each of them has numerous columns? In this case, I should use something like `json` and I have write long parser methods in both processes; and if I change some process, the other should be changed which is not a good practice